# How to find the coefficient of this Fourier sine series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

From $$1=\sum_{k\geq 1} a_k \sin((k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})x),$$
I want to find $a_k.$

My unsuccessful approach is first multiplying both side by $\cos((k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})x)$. That is,
$$\cos((k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}(\sin \pi x)a_k.$$

Can anyone give me a trick to find $a_k$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that $\sin(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(k\pi)$.  Then, you're simply finding the Fourier cosine series of the function $f(x)=1$ (which should be fairly straightforward using the definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The functions $ {\cos(k\pi x)}_{k=0}^{\infty} $ are orthogonal on the interval $[-1,1]$, that means

$$  \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(k\pi x) \cos(m \pi x) dx = \begin{cases} 0 &: k\ne m \\ 2 &: k=m=0\\ 1 &: k=m \ne 0 \end{cases}\, .$$